# LINQ join, then group by, into strongly-typed List of classes

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a `List<Scenario>` like this:

```
ScenarioNumber      Key     Value
1                   foo     bar
1                   fez     ben
2                   far     baz
2                   fem     bit
```

I have a `List<Mapping>` like this:

```
Key     MappingValue
foo     abc
fez     xyz
far     123
fem     bob
```

**Problem:** I want to join these two via `Key`, then group them by `ScenarioNumber` into a `List<ScenarioNode>`.

```
public class ScenarioNode
{
    public int ScenarioNumber { get; set; }

    public List<ScenarioArgument> Arguments { get; set; }
}
```

`ScenarioArgument` is a class with properties: `Key`, `Value`, and `MappingValue`.

I have the following and I'm stuck at the `Arguments =` part:

```
var scenarioFormats = from s in this.investment.Scenarios
                      join m in this.keyMappings 
                      on new { Key = s.Key, Level = "DEAL" } 
                      equals new { Key = m.Key, Level = m.Level } into sm
                      from scen in sm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      group s by s.ScenarioNumber into sg
                      select new ScenarioNode
                      {
                          ScenarioNumber = sg.Key,
                          Arguments = new List<ScenarioArgument> { } // <<-- now what?                 
                      };
```

Comment: What you need to do is shorten your query to just `select sg` and examine what each grouping contains in debug.  Once you see what data is being returned, you can formulate the `new ScenarioNode` code.  I strongly suspect your query isn't working the way that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could project an anonymous type that contains the `Scenario` and the `MappingValue`:

```
var scenarioFormats = from s in this.investment.Scenarios
                      join m in this.keyMappings 
                      on new { Key = s.Key, Level = "DEAL" }
                      equals new { Key = m.Key, Level = m.Level } into sm
                      from scen in sm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      group new { Scenario = s, scen?.MappingValue } by s.ScenarioNumber into sg
                      select new ScenarioNode
                      {
                          ScenarioNumber = sg.Key,
                          Arguments = sg.Select(s => new ScenarioArgument
                          {
                              Key = s.Scenario.Key,
                              Value = s.Scenario.Value,
                              MappingValue = s.MappingValue
                           }).ToList()
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You coult try this:

```
var scenarioFormats = from s in this.investment.Scenarios
                      join m in this.keyMappings on new { Key = s.Key, Level = "DEAL" } equals new { Key = m.Key, Level = m.Level } 
                      group new{Scenario=s,KeyMapping=m} by s.ScenarioNumber into sg
                      select new ScenarioNode
                      {
                        ScenarioNumber = sg.Key,
                        Arguments = sg.Select(e=>new ScenarioArgument
                                                 {
                                                   Key=e.Scenario.Key,
                                                   Value=e.Scenario.Key,
                                                   MappingValue=e.KeyMapping.MappingValue,
                                                 } 
                                             )                          
                      };
```

Just apply a join first, and then group both, `Scenario` and `Mapping`, by `Scenario.ScenarioNumber`, so, at the end you can project the result you are expecting in `Arguments` property using the resulted groups